# Efficient way to refactor a method with double if containing small differencies

Tags: java, refactoring

Im trying to refactor the following method but i didn't found a good solution:

```
private void check(SpecificData specificdata, Task task){
    if(specificdata instanceof MyData){
        MyData data = (MyData) specificdata;
        if(!data.getItemList()isEmpty){
            //SAME CODE
        }
    }
    if(specificdata instanceof OtherData){
        OtherData data = (OtherData) specificdata;
        //SAME CODE
    }
}
```

Im trying to avoid writing the same code but i don't know if it is possible. Have you got any suggestions?

Comment: Hi There, Why not make a new function with the common code and call that function from both the places ?

Comment: Running the same code in multiple places is called a method, is there a problem doing that?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what `//SAME CODE` actually is.

Answer (score -1):

I would use a polymorphic approach by making a subclass of SpecificData (or modifying it directly) with the functionality needed.
For example:

```java
/* SpecificData itself, or a class that extends SpecificData */
public class SomeData extends SpecificData {
 //contains the functionality needed in your 'SAME CODE' blocks
}

/* Special classes which extend SomeData */
public class MyData extends SomeData {}
public class OtherData extends SomeData {}

/* ...somewhere else... */
private void check(SomeData somedata, Task task){
    if(somedata instanceof MyData)//a special case of MyData
        if(((MyData) somedata).getItemList().isEmpty()) return;

    //run your 'SAME CODE' block here
}
```